# Elasticsearch word autocomplete with document counts

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I'd like to be able to autocomplete partial words to full words found in my documents and return a list of words and the number of documents those words are found in.

It would be great if I could also do this on an existing query results. So if they user typed "red tr" I would have results for all documents that match red and then words like truck or train with their counts.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Suggesters won't complete and give you document-frequency in the same go.

---

*One Solution:*

Performance won't be as zippy, but probably still acceptable if you do the following (not using Suggesters):

- Run a `size: 0` `match_all` query filtered using a [Prefix Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-prefix-filter.html) with your user's typed prefix.
- In the same query, request a [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) over a [shingled](https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles) field in your index.
- Use the aggregation results as your completion suggestions.

Note:

- See the section about [filtering term agg values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values) for noise suppression.  *(You'll need this since the default agg result ordering is by descending document count.)*
- Also, note that [document counts are approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts) wrt `shard_size` requested.

Comment: Unfortunately, Term Suggester doesn't do completion so it doesn't meet the need.